# Multiple Page on Python and QML

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I’m beginner on programming in python and qml and I'm doing a project 
My project need to have many UI forms I’m using qml to create these UI

Lets say we have Form A,B,C and when application load I need it to open Form A and form A contain button which I click and open Form B and Form A close, Form B it have button which I click it open form C and that form B close… Plis help me on these project

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("main", engine)


    ctx2 = engine.rootContext()
    ctx2.setContextProperty("main", engine)


    engine.load('form1.qml')
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    def pageC():
        engine.load('form3.qml')
        win2 = engine.rootObjects()[0]
        button1 = win2.findChild(QObject, "form3")
        button1.clicked.connect(pageC)
        win2.show()

    def newPage():
        engine.load('form2.qml')
        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
        win.show()




    button1=win.findChild(QObject, "form2")
    button1.clicked.connect(newPage)

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**form1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    maximumHeight: 200
    minimumHeight: 200
    maximumWidth: 200
    minimumWidth: 200


    Button {
        id: button1
        objectName: "form2"
        x: 22
        y: 71
        width: 157
        height: 59
        text: qsTr("Page a")
        onClicked: callPageB()
    }
}
```

**form2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    maximumHeight: 200
    minimumHeight: 200
    maximumWidth: 200
    minimumWidth: 200


    Button {
        id: button1
        objectName: "form3"
        x: 22
        y: 71
        width: 157
        height: 59
        text: qsTr("Page B")
        onClicked: callPageC()
    }
}
```

**form3.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    maximumHeight: 200
    minimumHeight: 200
    maximumWidth: 200
    minimumWidth: 200


    Button {
        id: button1
        x: 22
        y: 71
        width: 157
        height: 59
        text: qsTr("Page C")
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want me to do with the previous window? Do you want it to close?

Comment: Yes i want to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding qmls to `QQmlApplicationEngine` we can get through `rootObjects()`, so to do this I simply created the following class, but there are certain restrictions, each button inside the Window should have the `objectName` as the name of the file and must Be the children of Window:

**example.qml:**

```
Window {
    ...
    Button {
        objectName: "example"
    }
    ...
}
```

In the next part this class with the name of your qmls.

```
class Engine(QQmlApplicationEngine):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, qmls, parent=None):
        QQmlApplicationEngine.__init__(self, parent)

        [self.load("{}.qml".format(qml)) for qml in qmls]

        for i, root in enumerate(self.rootObjects()):
            if root != self.rootObjects()[0]:
                root.close()
            if root != self.rootObjects()[-1]:
                button= root.findChild(QObject, qmls[i])
                button.clicked.connect(self.closeAndOpen)

    def closeAndOpen(self):
        self.rootObjects()[self.counter].close()
        self.counter += 1
        self.rootObjects()[self.counter].show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = Engine(['form1', 'form2', 'form3'])
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have another issue on this i created login page which is start when user login meets with dashboard which have button for the next form, but when i add those solution it works fiine but when i click the button for calling the openCv camera it didn't work can you help me with that ..